# I want to find a pair of integers $X$, $Y$ which satisfy $X^2 - 2Y^2=1$ such that $X > Y > 50$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

> Find a pair of integers $X, Y$, which satisfy $X^2 - 2Y^2 = 1$, such that $X > Y > 50$.

I have started by finding a pair of much smaller integers that work: $X(1) = 3$ and $Y(1) = 2$.

When I looked up a solution it was as follows: 
$$\begin{array}
&X(2) = 3 × 3 + 4 × 2 = 17, & Y(2) = 2 × 3 + 3 × 2 = 12 \\
X(3) = 3 × 17 + 4 × 12 = 99, & Y(3) = 2 × 17 + 3 × 12 = 70
\end{array}$$
So $X = 99$ and $Y = 70$ is such a pair.

But what is the method used? I tried searching for similar questions, but didn't find an answer to this.

Comment: Hint: Pell numbers. You probably mean $x^2-2y^2=1$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes, thanks for pointing that out, edited now.  Thanks for the hint, gonna look it up now. :)

Comment: Check out Pell's equation in Wikipedia.

Comment: The Chakravala method does this.

Comment: Thanks all for the help! Now, at least I can put in the numbers into the equation and get a correct answer although I still don't understand the method lying underneath haha. I will hopefully learn this method in depth at school sometime later. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$X_{i+1}^2-2Y_{i+1}^2 = (3X_i + 4Y_i)^2 - 2(2X_i + 3Y_i)^2 =$$ $$ = (9-2\cdot4)X_i ^ 2 + (12-12)X_i \cdot Y_i + (16-2\cdot9)Y_i ^ 2= $$ $$= X_{i}^2-2Y_{i}^2 = 1$$

Comment: Please use \cdot for multiplication instead of periods.  Particularly when you write $2.4$ it looks like a decimal.  2 \cdot 4 gives $2 \cdot 4$

Answer (score 0):

Another (more naive) way of looking at this: we want all possible $k$ for which $(Y+k)^2-2Y^2=1$. Solving this for $Y$ (in terms of $k$) we get
$$
Y=k\pm\sqrt{2k^2-1}
$$
We will want to ignore the minus, since our solutions must be positive and we only want the solutions for when $\sqrt{2k^2-1}$ is an integer.

By inspection we get the first 4 solutions:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
k   & \sqrt{2k^2-1}& Y=k+\sqrt{2k^2-1}   & X=Y+k   \\ \hline
1   & 1            & 2   & 3   \\
5   & 7            & 12  & 17  \\
29  & 41           & 70  & 99  \\
169 & 239          & 408 & 577 \\
\end{array}
$$